# SQL: LIKE Clause to match the values

Tags: php, mysql, sql-like

I have a mobile validation field where it gives a message stating that the values exists if  we type the same number/values which is in the database else available if the value doesn't exists

Here is the query which am using at present :-

```
SELECT mobile FROM candidate_tabletest WHERE mobile  LIKE '%' '$mobile' '%'
```

The above query is not working in some cases . For example if we have number 123456789 in database and when we  type inside mobile field with code or any other format like  +91-123456789  it still says that mobile number is available .

For reference here is my HTML code for mobile field  :-

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="mobile" name="mobile"    placeholder="mobile" value="+91" onkeyup="checkmobile();" >
```

PHP code for checking:-

```
  <?php

   $host = 'localhost';
   $user = 'root';
   $pass = '';

   mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);

   mysql_select_db('appsrx1a_skyfler');

  if(isset($_POST['user_mobile']))
  {
   $mobile=$_POST['user_mobile'];

   $checkdata=" SELECT mobile FROM candidate_tabletest WHERE mobile  LIKE      '$mobile' '%' ";

    $query=mysql_query($checkdata);

   if(mysql_num_rows($query)>0)
  {
   echo '<span style="color:red;"><b>Mobile  Already Exists</b></span>';
  }
  else
    {
   echo '<span style="color:green;"><b> Available</b></span>';
     } 
 exit();
 }
```

If the number (123456789) is present in the database and even if the user types the mobile number as +91-123456789 or any other format . It should give a warning message stating that the number already exists .

Comment: the query you are doing compares '123456789' with '%+91-123456789%' which naturally is false. You may need % % on the mobile variable from the database as well, but that my leed to false positives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use concat  .. for build a proper string pattern

```
 SELECT mobile FROM candidate_tabletest WHERE mobile  LIKE concat( '%', '$mobile', '%' );
```

and as suggested  by Gordon Linoff   remmber to replace offending char

```
 SELECT mobile 
 FROM candidate_tabletest 
 WHERE mobile  LIKE concat( '%', REPLACE(REPLACE('$mobile', '-', '') , '+', ''), '%' );
```

If you need only for th right part of the mobile number then  you could use

```
 SELECT mobile 
 FROM candidate_tabletest 
 WHERE mobile  LIKE concat( '%', SUBSTRING_INDEX('$mobile', '-', -1), '%' );
```

Comment: I have tried this but no luck .. still gives same output as earlier

Comment: as suggested by GordonLinoff have you also replaced  the offending characters? .. anyway i have update the answer  hope is useful

Comment: Yes i tried that but this time its giving only One output  that is " available"

Comment: are you sure that you have not error in your query ?

Comment: now am able to offend special characters .. is it possible to offend numbers too.. for example if the number is  9123123123  and if we type +91-9123123123  it should offend +91-

Comment: you are want only the part to the right in   +91-9123123123  eg: 9123123123?

Comment: I have update the asnwer  for the right part condition

Comment: The updated code which you provided was really helpful and its working fine .thanks a ton

Answer (score 1):

One method would be to remove offending characters:

```
SELECT mobile
FROM candidate_tabletest
WHERE mobile LIKE REPLACE(REPLACE('%'.'$mobile'.'%', '-', '') , '+', '')
```

You could do this in the application layer as well, so `$mobile` only contains digits (which I presume is the format of the `mobile` column).

Comment: I tried this method but its giving only one output .. maybe am doing it wrong . Can you please provide a demo in  http://sqlfiddle.com/